# CORS request to embedded server (that cannot be changed)

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, xmlhttprequest

Under HTML4 I am able to create an XmlHttpRequest to retrieve an AJAX packet without issue; I am now porting to HTML5 - and I'm running into cors (never heard of it until today).  I am unable to make any modifications to the server since it is an embedded HTTP server that serves simple content.

here is the JS I am using:

```
var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://192.168.1.100/US/1.23/dynamic/readparval.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
```

Yes, I understand that my request is considered cross-domain but again this worked in HTML4.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: My first search for CORS shows:  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ , which suggests
  xmlhttp = new XDomainRequest();
Does this not work for you? If not, what errors do you see?

Comment: The server is a rom based http server - and it responeded with

Comment: Fiddler:

OPTIONS http://192.168.1.100/US/1.21/dynamic/readparval.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.100
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://sencha
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.45 Safari/537.22
Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, x-requested-with
Accept: */*
Referer: http://sencha/pump/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

Answer (score 0):

Can you proxy your request via an other server?  That proxy server would not be subject to CORS restrictions (imposed by the browser).

Browser extensions (in the case of chrome) can also bypass CORS checks by adding the domain to the permissions in the manifest.

Comment: I am trying to connect to an embedded system; although a proxy would solve the technical problem - I am unable to deploy such a beast as the IP in the request is usually un-routable (192...); and are typically deployed by our customers.

Comment: never tried this, but could use an iframe with the working html4?  Assuming this still works in the latest browser version.

Comment: iframe is not available since I am trying to develop an HTML5 mobile app :(